# Unable to render a nested resource's errors on parent resource show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, nested-resources

I have a basic "blog" application with posts and comments.  I'd like to allow users to comment on a post from `post#show` and I'm not exactly sure how to present comment validation errors on the post.

The code below nests comments under posts and will successfully create comments.  The issue when when a validation fails (such as a blank comment) the visitor is redirected to the post show page but the comment error messages are lost.

Right now `CommentsController#create` is redirecting the user to the `post` he was viewing.  Alternatively I had tried `render 'posts/show'` instead of a redirect but it ends up rendering the page at `posts/1/comments` instead of `posts/1`.

Any help getting errors for comment validations displayed on the posts/show template would be greatly appreciated.

#### Routes

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

#### Models

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post  
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { in: 6..20 }
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

#### Controllers

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end


# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      # SAVE works fine
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
    else
      # ERROR displays nothing on the post show page
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id)
  end
end
```

#### Views

```rb
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.content %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<h3>New Comment</h3>

<%= render 'comments/form', post: @post, comment: @post.comments.build %>
```

```rb
# app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [post, comment], local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note: I am trying to avoid `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if possible as for more complex use cases I find it to be extremely confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the error message because on a failed save attempt, you redirect to a  different controller/action; unsaved `@comment` object is not only gone, but also overwritten in view layer when comment form is rendered. Try rendering the `posts/show` view in `CommentsController#create` action.

```
if @comment.save
  # SAVE works fine
  redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
else
  render 'posts/show'
end
```

For this to work, you also need to move instantianting of a new comment from view to `PostsController#show` action.

```
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comment = Comment.new(post: @post)
  end
end
```

Iterate on `@comments` loaded in controller. New commment shouldn't be included among them. When rendering the form, use `@comment` variable. Remember to associate new comment with post before saving it.

```
<h2>Comments</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.content %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<h3>New Comment</h3>

<%= render 'comments/form', post: @post, comment: @comment %>
```

This way `posts/show` view should work with both controller actions; state of `@comment` object, along with it's errors, should be preserved after save attempt.

Comment: Building a new comment in `PostsController#show` will result in an empty comment being added to `@post.comments`.  When `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` prints the post's list of comments it will emit the extra empty one. :(  I got around this by changing it to ` @comment = Comment.new(post: @post)` but this seems to not use any of Rails' conventions. Ii've also had to add `@comment = Comment.new(comment_params); @comment.post = @post` to CommentsController#create... which seems unrailsy too

Comment: @BillyBlobSnortin you are right, I haven't noticed that. Updated my answer with a clean solution. Comments should be loaded from DB in controller action, not view.

Comment: Thank you for the update but the problem remains.  `@post.comments.build` mutates `@post.comments`.  I'm not sure if `build` is an option here?

Comment: I am sorry; I tried to provide cleaner solution and failed. Yes, `@post.comments.build` mutates contents of `@comments` variable. I checked the last project in which I had to implement a comment system, few years ago; I avoided the problem by loading comments before building a new one... but only those accepted by a moderator, so the new one wasn't included. Your solution is perfectly valid; there is nothing wrong with using `.new` for building new objects, that's what it is for. The fact that object has a `belongs_to` association doesn't change that. Skip `.build` if it gets in your way.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. This is one thing about rails that trips me up.. sometimes I "forget" that you can simply skip conventions if they are getting in the way!